# How do I get molecule to follow include_tasks correctly

Tags: ansible, molecule

```
TASK [Test: Install Test Authentication] ***********************************
fatal: [ubuntu2004]: FAILED! => {"reason": "Could not find or access '/home/test/test.playbook/molecule/default/test.yaml' on the Ansible Controller."}
```

Molecule handles files and templates fine relative to the .roles folder...why does this not occur for tasks when called via `include_tasks` :

```
- name: Install Test Authentication
  include_tasks:
    file: test.yaml
  when: test is defined
```

Folder structure is pretty simple.

```
~/playbook
  |___molecule
        |___default
              |___converge.yaml
  |___.roles
        |___ files
        |___ tasks
              |___ main.yaml <- called with no issues
              |___ test.yaml <- will not find when used in case above.
```

Obviously, there are other files...but my template tasks and file tasks work fine.....following their relative paths but tasks won't, why is this or what am I doing wrong. I can find no documentation and I am sure others have run into the issue, yet all I can find is the following:

https://github.com/ansible-community/molecule/issues/2171 which is about ansible-lint but its the closest thing I could find.

Also, there seems to be a total of 4 locations to discuss/ask questions regarding molecule....so I am not sure which will get answered first.

|TLDR;
How do I get molecule to follow include_tasks correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From what i see you have a wrong role structure.

Molecule folder should be in role folder.

[image: Example structure of molecule role]

This is from what you should start. After that recheck file naming. Recently i had common problem and it was, because lack of file extension.